# IOS permissions in Info.plist ignored when uploading app

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I am trying to build an ionic cordova app for IOS (we have only used android builds on this project until now), I have added the IOS platform from scratch, built in cordova, then opened the Xcode project, built, archived and uploaded. but then i get emailed an error regrading missing entries into my info.plist for "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" and "NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription".

So i went and added the two records with an explanation for their use in my apps info.plist

```
    <key>NSMicrophone​Usage​Description</key>
    <string>The app uses speech to text input to capture notes, this requires microphone access</string>
    <key>NSSpeech​Recognition​Usage​Description</key>
    <string>The app uses speech to text input to capture notes, this requires speech recognition use</string>
```

I have verified that those records end up in the built files info.plist that i then try uploading, but i still get the rejection email.

I thought it may need to be in the info.plist file of the API that requires those permissions, but even after adding the same values there i still get the rejection emails.

I have tried uploading from Xcode after the archiving finished and taking the Xcode archive, browsing inside it, getting just my .app, adding to a folder called Payload, compressing and renaming it to .ipa and uploading that to apple, with the same response.

Is there some file naming or folder structure that i am missing when i upload my files, i have checked that they all have the records that apple is asking for in all info.plist files but i still get the exact same rejection email when uploading

EDIT: the rejection email from apple
"
*Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "XXXX" 7.XX (7.XX). Please correct the following issues, then upload again. 
ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy). 
ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy). 
The App Store Team*
"

Comment: Do you put them in the right target plist? and exactly what response you get from Apple?

Comment: which one is the correct target? i have added it to <appname>-Info.plist (this pulls through to archives produscts\applications\<appname>.app) and to the info.plist of the api that requests microphone access (iSpeechSDK).

Comment: it should be Info.plist, it does not have a prefix.

Comment: The file in the archive is called "Info.plist", it is called "<appname>-Info.plist" in the source files. (I think the prefix is something ionic wants).

Comment: So probably you are doing the wrong info.plist. That's what I can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to clear your derived data.
set your deployment target to 9.0 or lesser maybe, when you change your target Xcode resets your info.plist.
prepare your Cordova application using the command : `cordova prepare`
once you prepared your application goto "-Info.plist" file and add the below description.

```
  <key>NSMicrophone​Usage​Description</key>
  <string>The app uses speech to text input to capture notes, this requires microphone access</string>
  <key>NSSpeech​Recognition​Usage​Description</key>
  <string>The app uses speech to text input to capture notes, this requires speech recognition use</string>
```

archive your application and uploadd to appstore. you will not get rejection.